# Sort keys and values in dictionary using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, dictionary

I just wrote some code adding data into this Dictionary:

```
    Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, double>> studentsExamsMarks = 
        new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, double>>();
        studentsExamsMarks.Add("Peter", new Dictionary<string, double>());
        studentsExamsMarks["Peter"].Add("History", 5.15);
        studentsExamsMarks["Peter"].Add("Biology", 4.20);
        studentsExamsMarks["Peter"].Add("Physics", 4.65);
        studentsExamsMarks.Add("John", new Dictionary<string, double>());
        studentsExamsMarks["John"].Add("History", 6.00);
        studentsExamsMarks["John"].Add("Biology", 3.75);
        studentsExamsMarks["John"].Add("Physics", 4.15);
        studentsExamsMarks.Add("Michael", new Dictionary<string, double>());
        studentsExamsMarks["Michael"].Add("History", 3.00);
        studentsExamsMarks["Michael"].Add("Biology", 3.95);
        studentsExamsMarks["Michael"].Add("Physics", 4.95);
```

How should I sort and print first by the name of the student (ascending order)and than by the value of the doubles in the inner dictionary or by the name of the subject? I`ll be very thankful if you show me both Versions. Thank you!

Comment: Please read [ask] and share your research. Grouping and sorting are very extensively documented on MSDN, the web and this site.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SelectMany` to get all inner dictionary entries to create an anonymous type with all properties. Then the ordering is simple with `OrderBy` and `ThenBy`:

```
var ordered = studentsExamsMarks
    .SelectMany(kv => kv.Value
        .Select(kvInner => new {Name = kv.Key, Subject = kvInner.Key, Value = kvInner.Value}))
    .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
    .ThenBy(x => x.Value);  // use x.Subject if you want to order by that instead

foreach (var x in ordered)
    Console.WriteLine($"{x.Name} {x.Subject} {x.Value}");
```